# I need to replace a String in java based on patterns

Tags: java

I want to remove everything between a html tag named "code" from a string named "answer". My code is as follows:

```
answer = answer.replaceAll("<code>*</code>","");
```

It is not working. Please help.

Comment: Java or JavaScript? They are not the same language.

Comment: java, by the way I got an answer for that.

Comment: You ***really*** want to use an XML parser for this instead.  Regex can only get you so far and will give you so much more heartache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
answer = answer.replaceAll("(?s)<code>.*?</code>","");
```